# How do I clean a visual studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have a solution that for several years has undergone quite a bit of abuse, lots of quick fixes and rushed features. As a result, the sln file itself and the TFS folder are quite a mess.

For me the way VS handles projects, solutions and the TFS structure is quite a mystery and we would like to fix the mess that has happened. What would be the best way to approach the problem? Should we create a new solution and copy our code over there?

Answer (score 1):

This is just something I do instinctively based on years of experience and knowledge of what .NET source code is and best practices for organizing and building it.  I don't know that there is a simple answer to teach you all the best practices and how to refactor it.

Comment: I'm looking for help on clean up of the solution, less on proper building.